# Laravel - SQLSTATE[42000] - UNION

Tags: sql, laravel

I am making a UNION between these two queries:

```
$first = 
    DB::table('pedido')
    ->select(DB::raw('date(fecha_pago) as fecha'),DB::raw('sum(subtotal) as ingreso'),DB::raw('0 as egreso'))
    ->where('idestado','=','2')
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('date(fecha_pago)'));

$second = 
    DB::table('egreso')
    ->select(DB::raw('date(fecha) as fecha'),DB::raw('0 as ingreso'),DB::raw('sum(monto) as egreso'))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('date(fecha)')); 

$final_query= 
    DB::select(DB::raw('date(fecha),sum(ingreso) as ingreso,sum(egreso) as egreso'))
    ->union($first)->union($second)
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('date(fecha)'))
    ->get();
```

I get the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'date(fecha),sum(ingreso) as ingreso,sum(egreso) as egreso' at line 1 (SQL: date(fecha),sum(ingreso) as ingreso,sum(egreso) as egreso)

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, please ask a specific question so people are able to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`DB::select()` executes a raw query, unlike `DB::table()->select()` which is used to define fields for the query builder to select.

You're missing the `DB::table()` in your final query, without it, you won't be using the query builder and you'll actually be running a query of just `date(fecha),sum(ingreso) as ingreso,sum(egreso) as egreso`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#selects

Comment: Yeah, but to initialize  the query builder, you need to use DB::table().  You might just want to use raw SQL for this entire thing.  Not sure if Laravel's query builder supports this, but maybe someone knows a way.

Comment: But I need to join two queries. 

Then, from the union of that result, group by the date and add the amounts.

In the $query_final I do not have a table because it is the union of two queries

Comment: Which is why I said "for the entire thing".